# Integral $\int_{0}^{\infty} u^{2}\left(e^{-4x(u^{-12}-u^{-6})}-1\right) \,\mathrm du$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, exponential-function

I need to find the integration of

$$I(x) = \int_{0}^{\infty} u^{2}\left(e^{-4x(u^{-12}-u^{-6})}-1\right) \,\mathrm du$$

I am given

$$e^{-4x(u^{-12}-u^{-6})}-1 \approx 
\begin{cases} 
-1 & \text{for}&  u \leq 1 \\
-4x(u^{-12}-u^{-6}) & \text{for} & u > 1
\end{cases}$$

Thank you for your help.

Comment: An explicit form can be found in WA: $$I(x) = \frac{\sqrt[4]{x} \left(2 \Gamma \left(\frac{1}{4}\right) \sqrt{x} \, _1F_1\left(\frac{1}{4};\frac{3}{2};x\right)+\Gamma \left(-\frac{1}{4}\right) \, _1F_1\left(-\frac{1}{4};\frac{1}{2};x\right)\right)}{6 \sqrt{2}}$$

Comment: @pmf i doesn't look impossible too proof that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using your approximation:
\begin{align*}
I(x) &= \int_0^\infty u^2\left( \exp \left(-4x(u^{-12}-u^{-6})\right) - 1\right) \,\mathrm du \\
&\approx \int_0^1- u ^2 \,\mathrm du + \int_1^\infty -4xu^2(u^{-12}-u^{-6}) \,\mathrm du\\
&= -\frac 13 -4x\int_1^\infty u^{-10}-u^{-4}\,\mathrm du \\
&=-\frac 13 -4x\left( \bigg[ \frac{u^{-9}}{-9}\bigg]^\infty_1 - \bigg[ \frac{u^{-3}}{-3}\bigg]^\infty_1\right) \\
&= \frac 89x-\frac 13
\end{align*}